# Quintus on PhoneGap

Tags: html, cordova

Has anyone got Quintus.js working on PhoneGap please?

Not sure whether the 2 are compatible. I am using phonegap for windows phone. 
I am noticing that it won't enter into the Q.load method. Any suggestions please? - can't find any related resources online.